# Not able to read XML because of spaces in XML file

Tags: java, xml, whitespace

I am facing a problem due to spaces in xml file. I want to read data from xml, but I face various problems due to spaces between nodes.

Ex.

`If a node has 4 childs, due to the spaces it shows 9 childs to the node.
So when I try to display node values in table, some columns without heading and without data are also created.`

`When I removed these spaces I  read my file successfully without any problem.`

So how fix such problem? Because everytime I can not personally remove white spaces from file, as I read multiple xml files. So it will be tedious job of removing spaces from every file.

```
Document doc;
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
doc = dBuilder.parse(fp);
doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();            
NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("parameter"); 
nodeName = name; 
for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength();temp++)
{
     Node nNode =  (Node) nList.item(temp);
     Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
     String upname1 = getTagValue("name", eElement);
     System.out.println(nodeName+"   UP:    "+upname1);

     if(upname1.equals(nodeName))
     {  
           NodeList pvalList = eElement.getElementsByTagName("paramvalues");
           for(int l=0; l< pvalList.getLength(); l++)
           {
                 Node pNode = (Node) pvalList.item(l);
                 NodeList valList = pNode.getChildNodes();

                 for(int j=0; j<valList.getLength(); j++)
                 {
                     Node valNode = (Node) valList.item(j);

                     if(valNode.getNodeName().equals("value"))
                     {
                          NamedNodeMap att = valNode.getAttributes();

                          for(int s=0; s<att.getLength(); s++)
                          {
                              Node n1 = att.item(s);
                              System.out.println("len:   "+att.getLength());
                              if(n1.getNodeName().equals("default"))
                                   def = n1.getNodeValue();

                              if(n1.getNodeName().equals("actualvalue"))
                                   aval = n1.getNodeValue();
                           }
                      }
                 }
           }
     }
}
```

I know this a strange problem, but its becoming irritating while completing my work.

Plz help.. Thanks..

Comment: Can you show your problematic Java code?

Comment: It's probably because your code doesn't check if a Node is an instance of 'Element'. You probably need to filter out 'text nodes'. It's quite easy but you'll need to show some code :)

Comment: 1. try and `normalize()` the XML data before parsing it. 2. please paste some code!

Comment: @amir75 Do I have to check it for every child node also?

Comment: Yes, for the nodelist of childNodes. When you iterate through the NodeList returned by getChildNodes(), whitespace would be returned as 'Text'  nodes, which are not instanceof Element. Hmm, looking at the code, it's not exactly the code I expected to see, but perhaps you only pasted part of it...

Answer (score 0):

You could try just making a class to TRIM whitespace from the left and right of the string while your parsing the document for Example **' John Smith '** becomes **'John Smith'** | src : http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Strip_whitespace_from_a_string/Top_and_tail

```
 public class Trims{
   public static String ltrim(String s){
      int i = 0;
      while (i < s.length() && Character.isWhitespace(s.charAt(i))){
         i++;
      }
      return s.substring(i);
   }

   public static String rtrim(String s){
      int i = s.length() - 1;
      while (i > 0 && Character.isWhitespace(s.charAt(i))){
         i--;
      }
      return s.substring(0, i + 1);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args){
      String s = " \t \r \n String with spaces  \t  \r  \n  ";
      System.out.println(ltrim(s));
      System.out.println(rtrim(s));
      System.out.println(s.trim()); //trims both ends
   }
```

or find a different way to deal with the content.. make use of DOMBuilder (http://www.java-tips.org/other-api-tips/jdom/dealing-with-mixed-content-whitespace-comments-text-child-elements-and.html)

```
        // a builder takes a boolean value meaning validation mode:
        DOMBuilder builder = new DOMBuilder(false);

        // simply load the document::
        Document document = builder.build(
                new java.io.File("sample.xml"));

        Element order = document.getRootElement();

        // find an address tag:
        Element address = 
                order.getChild("purchased-by").getChild("address");
```